# The name 'name' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am currently doing the Xamarin.iOS tutorial and I cant seem to get around this problem.

```
 translatedNumber = PhoneTranslator.ToNumber(PhoneNumberText.Text);
```

VS2015 underlines PhoneTranslator and gives me the following error:
"The name PhoneTranslator does not exist in the current context"

Both the ViewController class and the PhoneTranslator class are using the same namespace. How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

It worked after a forced restart of the computer. Don't know why it didn't work in the first place.

```
namespace Phoneword
{
    public static class PhoneTranslator
    {
        public static string ToNumber(string raw)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(raw))
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                raw = raw.ToUpperInvariant();
            }

            var newNumber = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var c in raw)
            {
                if (" -0123456789".Contains(c))
                {
                    newNumber.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = TranslateToNumber(c);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        newNumber.Append(result);
                    }
                }
                // otherwise we've skipped a non-numeric char
            }
            return newNumber.ToString();
        }

        static bool Contains(this string keyString, char c)
        {
            return keyString.IndexOf(c) >= 0;
        }

        static int? TranslateToNumber(char c)
        {
            if ("ABC".Contains(c))
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else if ("DEF".Contains(c))
            {
                return 3;
            }
            else if ("GHI".Contains(c))
            {
                return 4;
            }
            else if ("JKL".Contains(c))
            {
                return 5;
            }
            else if ("MNO".Contains(c))
            {
                return 6;
            }
            else if ("PQRS".Contains(c))
            {
                return 7;
            }
            else if ("TUV".Contains(c))
            {
                return 8;
            }
            else if ("WXYZ".Contains(c))
            {
                return 9;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

namespace Phoneword {
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            string translatedNumber = "";

            TranslateButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

                // Convert the phone number with text to a number
                // using PhoneTranslator.cs
                translatedNumber = PhoneTranslator.ToNumber(PhoneNumberText.Text);

                // Dismiss the keyboard if text field was tapped
                PhoneNumberText.ResignFirstResponder();

                if (translatedNumber == "")
                {
                    CallButton.SetTitle("Call", UIControlState.Normal);
                    CallButton.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    CallButton.SetTitle("Call " + translatedNumber, UIControlState.Normal);
                    CallButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            };

            CallButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => &gt;
            {
                var url = new NSUrl("tel:" + translatedNumber);

                // Use URL handler with tel: prefix to invoke Apple's Phone app,
                // otherwise show an alert dialog

                if (!UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url))
                {
                    var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Not supported", "Scheme 'tel:' is not supported on this device", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                }
            };
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    } }
```

Comment: what is PhoneTranslator?

Comment: You should show the current context.. Please show where `PhoneTranslator` is initialized and where is your current line of code in relation to it

Comment: I have added a link to the code. Im just trying to compile the code from a tutorial, but cant get around this problem.

Comment: you need to show your code and not the link to the tutorial - the problem is in your code and not there...

Comment: I copy/pasted everything. Nothing has changed. But alright, I will paste the entire code here

Comment: Code has been added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have copied your code into my visual studio 2015 and it doesn't complain about `PhoneTranslator`. Have you put the two classes in the same project? If you haven't been aware already, it is possible to create multiple projects under one solution.

*This should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet :(*

Comment: Everything worked after my computer had to restart. I have no idea why it didn't run in the first place, since it was already using the same namespace, and the classes were in the same project.

Comment: Sometimes VS can be bugged and I had to restart VS to bring it back to normal state :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed part of step 8, I had the same error. Adding the Text Field's name and saving the Main.storyboard handled the error in my case.
Step 8 says:
With the Text Field selected on the design surface, **change the Text Field’s Name property in the Identity
section of the Properties to *PhoneNumberText*** , and change the Text property to "1-855-XAMARIN":